# How can I clone a specific version of a firebase hosting site to another site?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

The [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-hosting-resources#cli-commands-cloning) indicate that it is possible to clone a specific version of a hosting site to another site and channel.

> firebase hosting:clone \ SOURCE_SITE_ID:@VERSION_ID 
> TARGET_SITE_ID:TARGET_CHANNEL_ID

However, in the [source of the CLI tool](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/51d2fd574a2c5e81bf51acb0b89409182edb40e9/src/commands/hosting-clone.ts#L36), it appears to split on either `:` or `@`, not both.

Regardless of the separator, when I run the following command, I get a 404. If I replace the `@version` with `:live` it copies the latest version from one site to another successfully.

```
firebase hosting:clone staging-asdf@f51931 portal-asdf:live
```

Comment: RE: Your comment about the CLI source: the code you linked tries to split by `:` first. Then, if either part is missing, it tries again with `@`. If either part is still missing, it throws an error.

Comment: Based on the quote you provided, shouldn't you be using `staging-asdf:@f51931` (with the colon)?

Comment: @samthecodingman I tried that first, following the docs, but I get this error

`Error: Could not find the channel @fcc391 for site staging-asdf.`

It seems clear that it is mistaking the version for a channel with that syntax.

Comment: @samthecodingman my point in linking to the docs and the code is that there seems to be a discrepancy. The docs say use `:` and `@`, but the code seems to use either `:` OR `@`.

Regardless, no variation I've tried works.